# How to prevent Django from accepting invalid dates and transforming them?

Tags: django, forms, date

I have the following Form:

```
class GuaranteesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    birth_date = forms.DateField(input_formats=['%d/%m/%Y'], required=True)
```

However if the user inserts an invalid date like: 13/13/1999 instead of raising an exception, Django converts the date by performing modulus of the day and month fields, and adding months and years accodingly. In the example, since the month is above 12, the Date which would get persisted would be 13/01/2000.

I'd much rather get an InvalidFormException, is there any way to prevent this behaviour?

I'm using Django on Jython (DOJ).

I've already implemented a solution through clean_birth_date, but I think it's rather ugly. What I'm looking for is a way to prevent this kind of behaviour with dates in general.

Comment: You could write your own clean method? def clean_birth_date(self): do stuff

Comment: I've already done that, but it seems silly to me that the default behaviour accepts month 13 and day 60.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rise an exception manually when [cleaning a specific form field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute).

Comment: I had already done that, but I don't really like it... I'm looking for something more generic.

Comment: Well since there's no cleaner solution available, I'll take your answer as the good one.